# Wordpress and wp.me redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect, curl, http-redirect

Just started playing around with cURL. I noticed a curious little link using the --head command. All my Wordpress sites hosted on my server have their own redirect link on http://wp.me For example the curl --head command returns a "Link ; rel=shortlink

I.e. `wp.me/2RI03` redirects from Wordpress to my site, `wp.me/1FaB8` redirects to TechCrunch which leads me to believe that they do this for every WP installation on the web. Just out of curiosity why would Wordpress be doing this?

Comment: http://jetpack.me/support/wp-me-shortlinks/

Comment: http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/shorten/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's just wordpress.com sites or jetpack:

http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/shorten/
http://jetpack.me/support/wp-me-shortlinks/